# Kotlin DSL for creating json objects (without creating garbage)

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to create a DSL for creating JSONObjects. Here is a builder class and a sample usage:

```
import org.json.JSONObject

fun json(build: JsonObjectBuilder.() -> Unit): JSONObject {
    val builder = JsonObjectBuilder()
    builder.build()
    return builder.json
}

class JsonObjectBuilder {
    val json = JSONObject()

    infix fun <T> String.To(value: T) {
        json.put(this, value)
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val jsonObject =
            json {
                "name" To "ilkin"
                "age" To 37
                "male" To true
                "contact" To json {
                    "city" To "istanbul"
                    "email" To "xxx@yyy.com"
                }
            }
    println(jsonObject)
}
```

The output of the above code is :

```
{"contact":{"city":"istanbul","email":"xxx@yyy.com"},"name":"ilkin","age":37,"male":true}
```

It works as expected. But it creates an additional JsonObjectBuilder instance every time it creates a json object. Is it possible to write a DSL for creating json objects without extra garbage?

Comment: Kotlin has to create a function object to be passed into `json { ... }`, so the "create no extra objects" problem is flawed from the start. The JVM is quite efficient in optimizing short lived objects anyways. Unless you benchmarked your code and are 100% sure that creating `JSONObjectBuilder ` instances is bottlenecking your performance, I wouldn't worry about this at all. (Personal note: I would make your builder an interface and hide the actual implementation in a private class, so you don't expose the json field.)

Comment: Yep, `json { ... }` should probably be `inline`

Comment: Did you create an artefact for these bits?

Comment: See github.com/holgerbrandl/jsonbuilder for a small DSL to create json with kotlin

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use a [Deque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) as a stack to track your current `JSONObject` context with a single `JsonObjectBuilder`:

```
fun json(build: JsonObjectBuilder.() -> Unit): JSONObject {
    return JsonObjectBuilder().json(build)
}

class JsonObjectBuilder {
    private val deque: Deque<JSONObject> = ArrayDeque()

    fun json(build: JsonObjectBuilder.() -> Unit): JSONObject {
        deque.push(JSONObject())
        this.build()
        return deque.pop()
    }

    infix fun <T> String.To(value: T) {
        deque.peek().put(this, value)
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val jsonObject =
            json {
                "name" To "ilkin"
                "age" To 37
                "male" To true
                "contact" To json {
                    "city" To "istanbul"
                    "email" To "xxx@yyy.com"
                }
            }
    println(jsonObject)
}
```

Example output:

```
{"contact":{"city":"istanbul","email":"xxx@yyy.com"},"name":"ilkin","age":37,"male":true}
```

Calling `json` and `build` across multiple threads on a single `JsonObjectBuilder` would be problematic but that shouldn't be a problem for your use case.

Comment: I love stacks, but doesn't this suffer from exactly the same issue (i.e. it creates a JSONObjectBuilder and JSONObject on every call to `json()`)? I think you're on the right track though - you'd just need to remember the result of the last call to `JSONObject.put()` so you could call `put()` on _that_ for nested fields instead of creating a new `JSONObject`. I hope that makes sense! :)

Comment: The example above creates only one JsonObjectBuilder and two JSONObject(s) which is far more better than the solution that I come up with.  The only thing is the final json string is in reversed order.

Comment: @HoundDog, In the `org.json.JSONObject` API you have to create a new `JSONObject` in order to nest it inside another so I do not believe there are any additional objects here. I hope that makes sense. :-)

Comment: @ilkinulas I printed my solution and it came out the same as your example output in your question. I do not believe that `JSONObject` maintains the ordering of keys though so from run-to-run you may get different ordering of keys. JSON keys are not ordered (think `HashMap` and not `LinkedHashMap`).

Comment: Great! put it to Maven repo plz :)

Comment: I've improved the solution and put it on github and jcenter, see github.com/holgerbrandl/jsonbuilder

Answer (score 23):

Do you need a DSL? You lose the ability to enforce `String` keys, but vanilla Kotlin isn't that bad :)

```
JSONObject(mapOf(
        "name" to "ilkin",
        "age" to 37,
        "male" to true,
        "contact" to mapOf(
                "city" to "istanbul",
                "email" to "xxx@yyy.com"
        )
))
```

Comment: I agree, this version is already looking like a DSL. But it creates temp arrays  and pairs.

Comment: I really like this solution for creating JSON in Java becuase it uses Kotlin's already clean DSL for creating JSON-like data but it has the same overhead as the example in the question. Each `mapOf` creates a new `Map` which is then copied and discarded for each `JSONObject` (including the nested `JSONObject` inside the top-level one).

Answer (score 9):

Updated on Jan 11 2023:
Replaced `infix fun String.to(json: Json -> Unit)` with `infix fun String.to(json: Json.() -> Unit)` which uses Json block as receiver and invokes after a Json object is created. So no longe need to add Json key inside Json object.

I am not sure if I get the question correctly. You don't want a builder?

```
import org.json.JSONArray
import org.json.JSONObject

class Json() : JSONObject() {

    constructor(init: Json.() -> Unit) : this() {
        this.init()
    }

    infix fun String.to(json: Json.() -> Unit) {
        put(this, Json().apply(json))
    }

    infix fun <T> String.to(value: T) {
        put(this, value)
    }

    infix fun <T> String.to(values: List<T>) {
        put(this, JSONArray().apply {
            values.forEach { put(it) }
        })
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val json = Json {
        "name" to "Roy"
        "body" to {
            "height" to 173
            "weight" to 80
        }
        "cars" to listOf(
            "Tesla"
            "Porsche"
            "BMW"
            "Ferrari"
        )
    }

    println(json)

}
```

You will get

```
{
  "name": "Roy",
  "body": {
    "weight": 80,
    "height": 173
  },
  "cars": [
    "Tesla",
    "Porsche",
    "BMW",
    "Ferrari"
  ]
}
```

Comment: this is very elegant

Comment: your answer looks good but what about JSONArray I'm a beginner in the kotlin so, can you explain to me how to handle JSONArray in the kotlin

Comment: @KishanDonga I am not sure what you want to achieve. I updated my answer, you can assign JSONArray as well.

Comment: @Arst What about array with custom object? When we print those, it adds backslash if nested json contains array of custom object.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible if you don't need any intermediate representation of the nodes, and if the context is always the same (the recursive calls are no different from each other). This can be done by writing the output immediately.

However, this severely increases code complexity, because you have to process your DSL calls right away without storing them anywhere (again, to avoid redundant objects).

Example (see its demo [here](http://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/k0lhmvdsvi29vipprunfrcccdh/6q8kkgb5815j5spuvjfsli21g4)):

```
class JsonContext internal constructor() {
    internal val output = StringBuilder()

    private var indentation = 4

    private fun StringBuilder.indent() = apply {
        for (i in 1..indentation)
            append(' ')
    }

    private var needsSeparator = false

    private fun StringBuilder.separator() = apply { 
        if (needsSeparator) append(",\n")
    }

    infix fun String.to(value: Any) {
        output.separator().indent().append("\"$this\": \"$value\"")
        needsSeparator = true
    }

    infix fun String.toJson(block: JsonContext.() -> Unit) {
        output.separator().indent().append("\"$this\": {\n")
        indentation += 4
        needsSeparator = false
        block(this@JsonContext)
        needsSeparator = true
        indentation -= 4
        output.append("\n").indent().append("}")
    }
}
```

```
fun json(block: JsonContext.() -> Unit) = JsonContext().run {
    block()
    "{\n" + output.toString() + "\n}"
}
```

```
val j = json {
    "a" to 1
    "b" to "abc"
    "c" toJson {
        "d" to 123
        "e" toJson {
            "f" to "g"
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't need indentation but only valid JSON, this can be easily simplified, though.

You can make the `json { }` and `.toJson { }` functions `inline` to get rid even of the lambda classes and thus you achieve almost zero object overhead (one `JsonContext` and the `StringBuilder` with its buffers are still allocated), but that would require you to change the visibility modifiers of the members these functions use: public inline functions can only access `public` or `@PublishedApi internal` members.

Comment: This is an interesting solution, but types are lost in the final json string. Every value is transformed to string.

Comment: @ilkinulas You can replace `\"$value\"` with `${JSONObject.valueToString(value)}` to retain the types.

Answer (score 2):

Found another solution. You can just inherit `JSONObject` class without need to create other objects.

```
class Json() : JSONObject() {

    constructor(init: Json.() -> Unit) : this() {
        this.init()
    }

    infix fun <T> String.To(value: T) {
        put(this, value)
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val jsonObject =
            Json {
                "name" To "ilkin"
                "age" To 37
                "male" To true
                "contact" To Json {
                    "city" To "istanbul"
                    "email" To "xxx@yyy.com"
                }
            }
    println(jsonObject)
}
```

The output of code will be the same.

```
{"contact":{"city":"istanbul","email":"xxx@yyy.com"},"name":"ilkin","age":37,"male":true}
```

**UPD**: If you use gson library you can look at this [awesome library](https://github.com/SalomonBrys/Kotson). It doesn't create any garbage, source code is easy to read and understand.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a library such as https://github.com/holgerbrandl/jsonbuilder to build json with

```
val myJson = json {
        "size" to 0
        "array" to arrayOf(1,2,3)
        "aggs" to {
            "num_destinations" to {
                "cardinality" to {
                    "field" to "DestCountry"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the library.